# connect the tty1 screen to my ssh session

Tags: ssh

I have a raspi and it has no mouse or keyboard.
But I have connected a Hardware-screen on it. And what I want is to connect via ssh or telnet to it, and see on the Hardware-screen what I am typing via ssh.

normally I use screen and attach to it with screen -x but that's not possible now because I have no keyboard attached to it.

Is there any way I can connect the tty1 to the ssh session ?

UPDATE1 , after I chmoded the tty1 for everybody writebale with

```
sudo chmod 666 /dev/tty1
```

I am able now to send messages to it like

```
echo "message" > /dev/tty1
```

There are still 2 problems. 1) I cant send "Enter", and 2) I do not see the feedback on my ssh screen.

Comment: `hexdump -C /dev/vcs1` should show you the content of `/dev/tty1`.

Answer (score 3):

You can run something like `screen` or `tmux` on the console, then connect to it. You can accomplish this by setting things (with `raspi-config`) to automatically log you in on the console and *not* start the GUI, and having the following as the last line in your `.bashrc`:

```
[[ $(/usr/bin/tty) == "/dev/tty1" ]] && exec /usr/bin/screen
```

You can then run `screen -x` from your ssh session. Several things to note:

- you will be a lot happier if the window size of whatever you are sshing from is the same as the console screen size (which you can see by running `stty -a < /dev/tty1`). Exactly what it is depends on what font you are using for the console.
- You will *still* not be able to see any messages printed by the kernel to the console (but you can see them with `sudo cat /dev/vcs1`).
- Check the manual for `screen` on how to adjust sizes, etc.

If you are really ambitious, you can write your own code that continously reads from /dev/vcs1, and "types" onto the console by using TIOCSTI.

Comment: what exactly is `[[ $(/usr/bin/tty) == "/dev/tty1" ]] && exec /usr/bin/screen` doing?

Comment: You only want to run this for the shell that starts on tty1. Is there any other way to interpret it?

Comment: I added [[ $(/usr/bin/tty) == "/dev/tty1" ]] && exec /usr/bin/screen to .bashrc and found out that your solution is almost good, the problem is nobody is pressing the final "Space Key or Return to start the screen". The second problem is after some minute or two the screen turns black and I can't wake it up any more

Comment: fix the power settings so that the screen never turns blank.